# mod_wsgi 403 forbidden (centos 6, pyramid)

Tags: linux, apache, permissions, centos, mod-wsgi

I have centos 6.5 server hosted on digitalocean. I installed mod_wsgi using 
    yum install mod_wsgi
My configuration file (/etc/httpd/config.d/wsgi.conf) was:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIDaemonProcess pyramid user=wsgi processes=1 \
   threads=4 \
   python-path=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
WSGIScriptAlias /testproject /home/wsgi/modwsgi/pyramid/testproject/pyramid.wsgi

<Directory "/home/wsgi/modwsgi/pyramid/testproject">
  #WSGIProcessGroup pyramid
  #Order allow,deny
  #Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I created new user wsgi and added it to sudo and apache groups. 
I created folder modwsgi in /home/wsgi and granted acces to it to wsgi user using

```
chown -R wsgi modwsgi
```

ls sayed:

```
[root@spiralarms wsgi]# ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 wsgi root 4096 May 16 09:35 modwsgi
```

from /home/wsgi directory as root.
Then i started httpd and opened http://spiralarms.ddns.net/testproject
I've got this message:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /testproject on this server.
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at spiralarms.ddns.net Port 80
```

Plz help

Comment: Usually caused by the home directory at '/home/wsgi' not being accessible to the user that Apache runs as.

Comment: I typed chmod 757 -R modwsgi/ and now it gives internal server error

Comment: If this is the Pyramid framework swallowing your error and creating a 500 response page, you will have to work out how to configure Pyramid to log the details of the exception if it doesn't already log it in the Apache error log. You have checked the Apache error log?